# Windows Search Protocol Host Error Message

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

My operating system is **Windows 10 Home version 1803** and I keep getting the following error message:

> The operating system is not configured to run this application

[image: error message window]

On investigation using the Windows Task Manager, I found out it has something to do with `SearchProtocolHost.exe` (something to do with Windows Search).

[image: Task Manager Window]
[image: SearchProtocolHost.exe Properties Window]

and it seems to only occur when I am running Outlook Version 1812 (Build 11126.20266 Click-to-run) which is part of my Microsoft Office 365 subscription.

From Event Viewer (as suggested in comments)

> Fault bucket 1602572720022102605, type 1
>   Event Name: APPCRASH
>   Response: Not available
>   Cab Id: 0
>   
>   Problem signature:
>   P1: SearchProtocolHost.exe
>   P2: 7.0.17134.471
>   P3: 6bf4ef1c
>   P4: mso20win32client.dll
>   P5: 0.0.0.0
>   P6: 5c342977
>   P7: 0140b1d2
>   P8: 001a5c34
>   P9: 
>   P10:

Does anyone know what is causing this and how to rectify it?

Comment: Event Viewer may give more details on the error.